# SQL Query like Condition not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in SQL Server and have values like that is enclosed in the quote. I am trying to filter the value which has `CC_` somewhere in the string. In the query when I try to filter the values using `%CC_%`, it is still returning the values though it is not present in the string.

```sql
with a as (
Select '@IDESC("Account"),@IDESC("Period"),@IDESC("View"),@IDESC("Scenario"),@IDESC("Version"),@IDESC("Years"),@IDESC("Currency"),@IDESC("Product"),@IDESC("FX View"),@IDESC("Data_Type"),@IDESC("Entity"),@IDESC("Function"),@IDESC("Market"),@IDESC("Business_Unit"),@IDESC("Reporting_Unit")'
as val)
select * from a where val like '%CC_%'
```

Can experts please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match literal underscore in a SQL Server `LIKE` expression, you may place it into square brackets:

```sql
SELECT * FROM a WHERE val LIKE '%CC[_]%';
```

Underscore `_` in a `LIKE` expression literally means any single character, and `%` means zero or more characters.

Comment: Thank you: I didn't know the underscore as single joker. Your answer begs the question how to you escape square brackets?

Comment: Use backslash, which can also be used to escape underscore as well.

Comment: The official documentation describe all the wildcards and escape options.